# Updating with Repository Merge API

Tags: sqlite, typeorm

Updating a relationship in my SQLite database using `Repository.merge` is not working.

```
const id = eventData.payload[0];
const itemUpdate = eventData.payload[1];

const requesterHasPermission =
  eventData.user.hasPermission?.('update-item');

if (requesterHasPermission) {
  const item = await ItemRepository.findOneByOrFail({
    id,
  });
  const updatedItem = ItemRepository.merge(item, itemUpdate);
  const errors = await validator(updatedItem);

  if (errors.length) {
    return {
      errors,
      code: 'VALIDATION_ERR',
      status: 'ERROR',
    } as unknown as IResponse<IPOSValidationError[]>;
  }

  const data = await ItemRepository.save(updatedItem);
  return {
    data,
    code: 'REQ_OK',
    status: 'SUCCESS',
  } as IResponse<typeof data>;
}
```

But after the `Repository.save`, the `item` relationships (Image, Brand, and Category) did not update.

Item Model:

```
@Entity('items')
export class Item {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  system_id: number;

  @Column()
  supplier_id: string;

  @Column({
    nullable: true,
  })
  image_id: number;

  @Column()
  category_id: number;

  @Column()
  brand_id: number;

  ...other properties...

  @OneToOne(() => Image, {
    eager: true,
    cascade: true,
  })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'image_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  image: Image;

  @OneToOne(() => Brand, { eager: true, cascade: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'brand_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  brand: Brand;

  @OneToOne(() => Category, { eager: true, cascade: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'category_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  category: Category;

  @OneToOne(() => Supplier, { eager: true, cascade: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'supplier_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  supplier: Supplier;

  @OneToOne(() => System, { eager: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'system_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  system: System;
}
```

- How can I make this work?
- And can I really use Merge API in updating relationships?

ps:
This is an Electron app (electron-react-boilerplate).

Thank you!!!